# Groovy method "no signature" String argument and String return

Tags: string, groovy

I have a beginner question about using Groovy.  I had thought this is a simple, unchallenging code snippet.

```
  def getName( str ){
    def rslt = "(none)";
    str.eachMatch( /$[TABLE_NAME:[a-zA-Z]]^/ ){
        -> patrn

        if( "(none)" == rslt ){
            rslt = patrn;
        }
    }//eachMatch

    return rslt;
}//getName
```

The idea is to return the first match to regex from the string '*str*' passed, and the matching string in '*rslt*'.

Instead I have this kind of error.

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
    No signature of method: All_Tables$_main_closure1.getName() 
      is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) 
        values: [Action]

        Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String) 
          at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:379)
          at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
          at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
          at ...
          at All_Tables$_main_closure1.doCall(All_Tables.groovy:31)
          at ...
          at groovy.sql.Sql.eachRow(Sql.java:1186)
          at ... 
          at All_Tables.main(All_Tables.groovy:26)
```

The call, it seemed straightforward:

```
static void main( String args[] ){
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(
            "jdbc:mysql://dev:3306/dbname",
            "dbuser", "dbpass", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );

    sql.eachRow( "SHOW TABLES;" ){
        str = it[0].toString();
        nam = getName( str );
    };

}//main
```

What curled my toes is that the Groovy documents mention that basic Java and Groovy libraries (such as java.lang.String) are included. Yet the signature fails on String.

I know this much.  When I do this small piece of code with jRuby, is just works.  None of this '*signature*' nonsense.

... Any advice welcome :-)

Will

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be exact as you omit a lot of context from your question, but it looks like you are trying to call a non-static method from the static main method.

Try either making getName static, or call it on an instance of your enclosing class